# Foreground Notification in service not working when app closed

Tags: android, service, intentservice, foregroundnotification

I have two services IntentService, Service. In IntentService i do calculation every minute, in service just showing foreground notification updating every second with timer, when i closed app, the IntentService cancels the foreground Notification by calling onCreate() again.

My question is their any way to

1. show notification in one service
2. how to not block foreground notification by another service, any help please suggest